# Как узнать имеется ли хоть одна сессия

Tags: ruby-on-rails, сессия

Есть такой код:

```
def index
  session[:conversations] ||= []

  @profiles = Profile.all.where.not(id: current_profile)
  @conversations = Conversation.includes(:recipient, :messages).find(session[:conversations])
end

def create
   @conversation = Conversation.get(current_profile.id, params[:profile_id])

   unless conversated?
     add_to_conversations
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js
     end
   end
end

private

def add_to_conversations
  session[:conversations] ||= []
  session[:conversations] << @conversation.id
end

def conversated?
  session[:conversations].include?(@conversation.id)
end
```

Нужно в методе conversated? узнать есть ли хоть одна действующая сессия

Comment: Что есть "действующая сессия"?

Comment: Открытый диалог

Comment: Сессия где хранится? Можно увидеть Rails.application.config.session_store ?

Comment: Что есть диалог, как понять что он открытый? Вы заменяете одни вопросы на другие :)

Comment: Где находится Rails.application.config.session_store. Я не могу найти

Comment: @SteepBeaver Обычно в config/initializers/session_store.rb Можно поискать session_store по проекту.

Comment: Данный файл отсутствует в проекте

Comment: Какой-то у вас, я полагаю, должен быть. Попробуйте получить вышеописанный объект в отладочной сессии (`binding.pry` с гемом pry или `binding.irb` для Ruby 2.4+, или что-нибудь ещё).

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. А чем обусловлен данный интерес?

Comment: По умолчанию Rails не хранит сессии централизовано, а сохраняет данные в cookies в браузере пользователя (шифруя информацию с использованием secret_key_base из config/secrets.yml). Если это ваш случай, получить информацию о сессиях "малой кровью" не представляется возможным. Однако, если вы сессии сохраняете в базе данных или в NoSQL решении, напротив, задача сильно упрощается. Однако, чтобы корректно ответить на вопрос или посоветовать альтернативное решение нужно знать, где вы храните сессии.

Comment: Но проще, наверное, отвязать задачу от сессий и искать решение для **пользовательской** проблемы, а не технической.

Comment: Для наглядности, я добавил метод index и изменил create в шапке вопроса. Я попытался сделать так: `@conversations.length > 1` для проверки количество диалогов в методе create, но при наличии одного открытого диалога, он все равно открывает второй. Я пытаюсь вывести значение `@conversations.length`, но из-за большого объема информации в консоли это довольно трудно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подошел к этому вопросу с другой стороны. Так как мне надо иметь только один открытый диалог (одну сессию), то при открытии другого диалога, я обнуляю сессию.

```
def create
  @conversation = Conversation.get(current_profile.id, 
  params[:profile_id])

  unless conversated?
    nil_conversation!
    add_to_conversations

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end

def nil_conversation!
  session[:conversations] = []
end
```